# декоратор - запуск функции

Tags: python, декоратор

Мне нужно написать декоратор, который последовательно запускает функции (указаны ниже), выдает ошибку RunTimeerror если все функции завершились с ошибкой. Не могу понять в чем проблема,

```
def call_rectifier(func1, func2, func3, func4):
    def inner():
        try:
            func1()
        except: 
            try: 
                func2()
            except:
                try:
                    func3()
                except:
                    try:
                        func4()
                    except: print ("Runtime error")
    return inner
def f1():
    return 1
def f1_2():
    raise Exception
def f2():
    return 2
def f3():
    return 1
def f4():
    return 1
```

При банальной проверке выдает ошибку

```
wrapper = call_rectifier(f1, f2, f3, f4)
assert wrapper() == 1
```

Comment: Как минимум, `wrapper()` никогда не будет равен 1 и всегда будет равен None, потому что ваша функция inner ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 0):

Так надо же `return` поставить перед вызовом каждой из функций внутри `inner`, иначе при вызове `inner` вернётся `None`, что у вас и происходит:

```
def call_rectifier(func1, func2, func3, func4):
    def inner():
        try:
            return func1()
            ^^^^^^
        ...
```

А вообще всё это можно гораздо короче написать, без повторения кода, если использовать список функций:

```
def call_rectifier(funcs):
    def inner():
        for f in funcs:
            try:
                return f()
            except:
                pass
        print ("Runtime error")
    return inner

...

wrapper = call_rectifier([f1_2, f1, f3, f4])
```